# silent crash Win7 64bit on ResumeLayout() with winforms and C#

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I'm building a Windows Forms application in C#, and testing on Windows 7 64bit revealed a silent crash.

The exact line that it fails on is `this.ResumeLayout(false);` near the end of the `InitializeComponent()` function. It's a part of the Visual Studio generated code from the Forms Designer.

There is no exception, no popup to show the program has crashed, nothing. It simply ceases to run once it hits that line. This only occurs in 64bit. Removing that line, the program runs, but cannot be maximized, and there are several other oddities related to window properties.

I've tried everything from changing build settings to using *CorFlags.exe*, nothing has helped. What could be the issue?

If it makes a difference, I'm using OpenTK and the GL Controls.

Comment: It could just be [this know issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/357311/silent-exceptions-on-x64-development-machines) with silent exceptions. The most thoroughly annoying bug. Maybe you could enclose `InitializeComponent();` in a try catch block and figure out what the real exception is.

Comment: Hmmm, that is definitely interesting. I have a try catch block around the Application.Run() hoping to catch something, and nothing happened there, I'll try one around InitializeComponent() and see if that catches anything. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Had an identical problem, only in my case the software ran on some 64-bit systems and not others.  For example, my laptop is a vaio pcg series bought just this year.  64-bit Windows 7 Home Edition, 1600 x 900 resolution.  Program runs just fine here.  My colleague has a vaio svz series, 64-bit Windows Professional with 1920 x 1080 resolution, and for some reason his kept getting the silent crash on the `ResumeLayout(false)` call.

Again, commenting out the `this->SuspendLayout()` call near the top of the `INitializeComponents()` sub, and the `this->ResumeLayout(false)` call near the bottom fixed the problem, and the program seems to run fine on both systems now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem with ResumeLayout().  It ran fine on several machines, but I had one user who had it throwing "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."  Not very helpful.  Unfortunately they also hide some of the details from Exception.StackTrace.  I consulted with our resident expert and he felt it was a resizing issue.  I discovered exactly where the problem was after going to DEBUG-->Exceptions and selecting everything.  I then got a break right inside a function I was using to reposition some checkboxes.  For some reason this was throwing an out of range exception on this user's box...

Rectangle rect = dataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(col, row, true);

The point being that selecting the break on exceptions options as I described helped me pinpoint the actual problem.  The workaround that others mentioned is fine, but in this case I was able to find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use some external component?
Some OCX which is not compatible with 64bit? I had your same trouble using GdPicture.
If so, try to compile for 32bit and problem could be solved.

Comment: I'm not using anything aside from OpenTK with my project, and I've tried compiling for x86, Any CPU, etc. none have made any difference. An OpenTK app WITH interop using user32.dll works just fine on a 64bit machine, but once Windows Forms becomes involved, it crashes like this.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this whole ordeal was to simply remove both the offending ResumeLayout() call and its corresponding SuspendLayout() call at the beginning of the InitializeComponent() function. It seems to have had no ill effect on the layout of the window despite having a heavy number of controls on the window. Again, this was only for 64 bit machines, the issue never popped up on Windows XP or 7 32 bit.

I'm still baffled as to why the ResumeLayout() call was causing a silent crash in the first place, and still feel slightly uneasy about the "solution", but it seems to have worked.